# Selecting from a list of tuples

Tags: list-manipulation, filtering

Given a list tuples `Tuples[Range[10],2]` I'd like to select the ones that match a certain criteria. Namely that for every pair `{x ,y}`, `GCD[y, x] == 1` and `Mod[x, y] != 2`

I've tried the following.

```
Select[Tuples[Range[10], 2], Function[{x, y}, GCD[x, y] == 1 && Mod[x, y] != 2]]
```

But, I understand I'd have to supply the function with a symbol (and not a list).

How could I filter out that list of tuples?

Comment: `Tuples[Range[10], 2] // 
 Select[GCD[#[[1]], #[[2]]] == 1 && Mod[#[[1]], #[[2]]] != 2 &]`

Comment: I tried something similar before, without the `&` at the end. It didn't work. Said `#1` had no attributes or something akin to that. Why does it work with the `&` at the end?

Comment: @Rodrigo - See the documentation for [`Function`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Function.html). When using a pure function with formal parameters (e.g., `#1`), the `&` is needed to mark the end of the pure function's body.

Comment: `Select[Tuples[Range[10],2],Apply[Function[{x,y},GCD[x,y]==1&&Mod[x,y]!=2]]]`

Answer (score 12):

You may use [`Apply` (`@@`)](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Apply.html).

```
Select[
 Tuples[Range[10], 2], 
 Function[tupe, GCD@@tupe == 1 && Mod@@tupe != 2]
]
```

> ```
> {{1,1},{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{1,6},{1,7},{1,8},{1,9},{1,10},{2,1},{3,1},{3,2},
>  {3,4},{3,5},{3,7},{3,8},{3,10},{4,1},{4,3},{4,5},{4,7},{4,9},{5,1},{5,2},{5,4}, 
>  {5,6},{5,7},{5,8},{5,9},{6,1},{6,5},{6,7},{7,1},{7,2},{7,3},{7,4},{7,6},{7,8},
>  {7,9},{7,10},{8,1},{8,5},{8,7},{8,9},{9,1},{9,2},{9,4},{9,5},{9,8},{9,10},{10,1},
>  {10,3},{10,7},{10,9}}
> ```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

Another option is to use `Cases`

```
ClearAll[x,y];
data = Tuples[Range[10], 2];
Cases[data, {x_, y_} /; GCD[x, y] == 1 && Mod[x, y] != 2 :> {x, y}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Answer (score 5):

Instead of building a huge list and then filtering it down, it can be much more efficient to build the list directly with `Solve` or `SolveValues`:

```
SolveValues[GCD[y, x] == 1 && Mod[x, y] != 2 && 1 <= x <= 10 && 1 <= y <= 10,
            {x, y}, Integers]

(*    {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8},
       {1, 9}, {1, 10}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5},
       {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {3, 10}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 7},
       {4, 9}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {5, 9},
       {6, 1}, {6, 5}, {6, 7}, {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 6},
       {7, 8}, {7, 9}, {7, 10}, {8, 1}, {8, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 9},
       {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {9, 5}, {9, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 1},
       {10, 3}, {10, 7}, {10, 9}}                                         *)
```

Answer (score 4):

I also made a function that combines Tuples and Select: saving sometimes a lot of memory:

```
ResourceFunction["SelectTuples"][Range[10], 2, (GCD @@ #) == 1 && (Mod @@ #) != 2 &]
```

Answer (score 4):

**Using `CoprimeQ`:**

```
data = Tuples[Range[10], 2];
Select[data, CoprimeQ @@ # && (Mod @@ #) != 2 &]
```

or

```
Pick[#, CoprimeQ @@ # && (Mod @@ #) != 2 & /@ #] &@data
```

---

> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {1,
> 9}, {1, 10}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3,
> 8}, {3, 10}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 7}, {4, 9}, {5, 1}, {5,
> 2}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {5, 9}, {6, 1}, {6, 5}, {6,    7},
> {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 6}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}, {7,    10},
> {8, 1}, {8, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 9}, {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {9,    5}, {9,
> 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 1}, {10, 3}, {10, 7}, {10, 9}}

Answer (score 4):

Stealing ideas from Roman and Syed:

```
f0 = If[CoprimeQ @ ## && UnequalTo[2] @* Mod @ ##, {##}, Nothing] &;

Catenate @ Array[f0, {10, 10}]
```

> ```
> {{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8},
>  {1, 9}, {1, 10}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, 
>  {3, 8}, {3, 10}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 7}, {4, 9}, {5, 1},  
>  {5, 2}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {5, 9}, {6, 1}, {6, 5},  
>  {6, 7}, {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 6}, {7, 8}, {7, 9},   
>  {7, 10}, {8, 1}, {8, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 9}, {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 4},   
>  {9, 5}, {9, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 1}, {10, 3}, {10, 7}, {10, 9}}
> ```

Comment: Why not `Nothing` instead of `##&[]`?

Comment: @Roman, good point; thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using `CoprimeQ`, `GroupBy` and `Extract`:

```
data = Tuples[Range[10], 2];
Extract[GroupBy[data, CoprimeQ @@ # && (Mod @@ #) != 2 &], Key[True]]

(*Thanks for your idea, Syed!*)

(*{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {1, 9}, {1, 10},
{2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3, 8}, {3, 10}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, 
{4, 5}, {4, 7}, {4, 9}, {5, 1}, {5, 2}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {5, 9}, 
{6, 1}, {6, 5}, {6, 7}, {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 6}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}, 
{7, 10}, {8, 1}, {8, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 9}, {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {9, 5}, {9, 8},
{9, 10}, {10, 1}, {10, 3}, {10, 7},{10, 9}}*)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
data = Tuples[Range[10], 2];
```

Using `SequenceCases`

```
SequenceCases[data, {a_} /; GCD @@ a == 1 && Mod @@ a != 2 :> a]
```

{{1, 1}, {1, 2}, {1, 3}, {1, 4}, {1, 5}, {1, 6}, {1, 7}, {1, 8}, {1,
9}, {1, 10}, {2, 1}, {3, 1}, {3, 2}, {3, 4}, {3, 5}, {3, 7}, {3,
8}, {3, 10}, {4, 1}, {4, 3}, {4, 5}, {4, 7}, {4, 9}, {5, 1}, {5,
2}, {5, 4}, {5, 6}, {5, 7}, {5, 8}, {5, 9}, {6, 1}, {6, 5}, {6,
7}, {7, 1}, {7, 2}, {7, 3}, {7, 4}, {7, 6}, {7, 8}, {7, 9}, {7,
10}, {8, 1}, {8, 5}, {8, 7}, {8, 9}, {9, 1}, {9, 2}, {9, 4}, {9,
5}, {9, 8}, {9, 10}, {10, 1}, {10, 3}, {10, 7}, {10, 9}}